# Am I missing something by using outdated data cable and wall charger?

Tags: data-synchronization, charging, iphone

My wife has iPhone 3G and I recently bought iPhone 4 for myself. Since we can easily manage charging for both of our phones from just one wall charger, I actually never unpackaged mine and data cable is still packed as well.

But few days ago I noticed that my phone refusing to sync with even older data cable (from 3rd gen iPod nano) although iPhone 3G does sync with it.

So that got me thinking, do I missing something by not using updated accessories? Faster charging time or data sync maybe? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a total of 5 charging cables (and my partner has another 4) ranging from the 3G days until now. I still use my original 3G cable (the one where you had to press buttons on the side to release it) to plug my iPhone 4 into my iMac, and nothing has gone wrong so far :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the same cables across all my Apple devices (I have so many around, and can't really tell them apart any more).  One bit of caution regarding the **wall plug**, though: there was one model that shipped with either the original iPhone or the 3G which was recalled because it was prone to overheating.

If you haven't run into a problem with yours by now, it's probably not an issue.  Just wanted to offer the heads-up.

Comment: FYI it was with the iPhone 3G.